# Coloring ggplot for density histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

So I have the histogram below, which gives me what I needed:

```
n <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=carat)) + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density.., 
     fill= ..count..)) + geom_density(aes(x=carat))
```

So how do I make the scale color of the histogram go from red to green? I've tried this:

```
n +scale_color_gradient(low="green", high="red")
```

And it does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: You want different colors for the bars of the histogram? And I assume you want the fill so probably use `scale_fill_gradient` rather than `scale_color_gradient`

Comment: @MrFlick Oh, it does the trick now. Thanks!